# Can i Build Circular heat map using highchart

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I want to build As follows image
Can i Build Circular heat map using highchart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr2Hn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular heatmap is not supported by default in Highcharts, but with additional code you can create **polar** `heatmap` chart:

```
chart: {
  type: 'heatmap',
  polar: true
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kxznatLf/

Comment: Thank you for your answer : )